# WiFi card (Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260) sees only 1 network but no signal. Disable/enable in Device Manager fixes temporarily (Windows 10 Home)

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop

On my ASUS UX501J (or N501JW depending upon the sticker versus System Information table) I have an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 network adapter.  It had been working great until a few weeks ago when the following behavior started happening:

1. All internet connection is lost.
2. The WiFi icon still shows as connected to the current WiFi network, but no other nearby networks show on the list.
3. Toggling airplane mode does not solve it.
4. Disabling/Re-Enabling the *AC 7260* in the Device Manager (Windows 10 Home, currently 10.0.18363) does solve it; it can then see all networks and the WiFi works again.
5. This problem does NOT exist on immediate start-up (so rebooting solves the problem).
6. The connection is lost automatically (not based upon my actions) and does not appear to occur on any schedule.

These observations make me think it's a hardware issue.  I have already updated all my drivers (WiFi card was already running the latest 18.33.5.1; updating BIOS did not solve it), but the fact that doing a software disable/enable makes me think it's not a hardware loose connection.

Any suggestions on what to do?  I know I can always buy an external USB card, but that seems like a waste.

Comment: What was the last cumulative update you installed?  There was an issue, that makes me believe, this is a known issue.  However, without the information I am asking for, it's impossible for me to research the problem.

Comment: [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1909#406msgdesc) issue sort of matches your description.  However, unless you are using a VPN, I doubt that is the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't manually installed a cumulative update in years, if ever on this laptop.  The automated Windows updates perform regularly without my prompting (or consent for that matter).  I am currently running 10.0.18363 Build 18363.  If you can direct me where to find my update history I will gladly share it.  And negative, not using a VPN/proxy.

Comment: Cumulative updates are installed automatically.  It does not matter but the build number you provided isn't accurate and/or incomplete.  Which is the reason I asked for which cumulative update you last installed.  Windows Update History can be displayed from Windows Update within Settings.

Comment: What about a proxy?  The issue I talked about happens if your using a proxy or VPN.  Be sure to install KB4554364 to see if that fixes the problem.  You will have to download it manually from the Windows catalog website yourself

Comment: @Ramhound I was not using a VPN but upgraded to KB4554364 anyway.  After restart my WiFi was gone but disable/re-enable worked.  It died again about an hour later following the same symptoms I described originally.